# Can I store Unicode from PHP to MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord

I'm trying to save a string:

```
`Error Number: 1366</p><p>Incorrect string value: '\xCC\xC7 Ree...' for column 'ShipToName' at row 1</p><p>INSERT INTO `default_orders` (`OrderNumber`, `ShipCarrier`, `ShipService`, `ShipDate`, `ShipToName`, `ShipToAddress1`, `ShipToAddress2`, `ShipToCity`, `ShipToState`, `ShipToZip`, `ShipToCountry`, `ShipToPhone`, `SKU1`, `ProdName1`, `Qty1`, `batch_id`, `timestamp`, `client_id`, `status`) VALUES ('LIFEG-1004648', 'USPS', 'First Class Mail', '', 'Zo�� Reed', '17`
```

But it won't save. I'm using CodeIgniter Active record if that matters.

Comment: What is your input encoding and your destination COLLATION?

Comment: MySQL COllation is: utf8_unicode_ci. The field is of type `TEXT`

Comment: What is your input encoding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `form_open('controller/function')` function in your HTML, it adds the `accept-charset="utf-8"` to the form, change your collation to `utf8_bin` and try once.